# IR Remote Database

Tags: raspberry-pi, remote-control

I am looking for an IR remote control database.

I found one from [Remote Central](http://www.remotecentral.com/cgi-bin/codes/).

but, this database does not include upcoming infrared operated devices information.

Will you please suggest to me, any latest & largest set of IR remote databases where I can find the IR codes for the different types of remotes?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community : Updated the question now.

Answer (score 0):

This website has a list of free and open source resources on IR: http://www.harctoolbox.org/IR-resources.html

It includes, amongst others, :

- [irdb](https://github.com/probonopd/irdb)
- [lirc](http://lirc-remotes.sourceforge.net/)
- [a hifi-remote forum post with an Excel sheet](http://www.hifi-remote.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=12235)
- [GirrLib](https://github.com/bengtmartensson/GirrLib)